# Ellipticity of certain differential operator associated to a pair of vector field via curvature tensor

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-operators, index-theory

What is a precise example of the following situation:

A compact Riemanian manifold $M$ admits two vector field $X,Y$ such that the the operator $$Z\mapsto R(X,Y)Z$$
Would be an elliptic operator and the index of operator can be computed precisely?

In this question $R$ is the curvature tensor associated to the Riemannian metric.

Comment: This is a skew-symmetric  endomorphism of the tangent bundle $TM$. As such  it is elliptic if and only if it is a bundle isomorphism in which case  the index is zero.  Note that    if $X,Y$ are collinear at a point  the endomorphism is zero at that point. In particular  it shows that for this operator to be invertible it is necessary that you can find two vector fields which are linearly independent  at each point of $M$. This constrains the topology of $M$. For example, the Euler characteristic  has to be zero.

Comment: @DeaneYang  yes. Before that I ask this question I did not pay attention to the fact that the curvature is tensorial in all its 3 variables.thank you for comments of you and Liviu.

Comment: Liviu’s answer can also be said as follows: the differential operator is zeroth order and therefore just a matrix-valued function of the manifold. It is elliptic if and only if the matrix is invertible.